# suddenly user_engagement event is missing in firebase analytics dashboard

Tags: android, firebase, ionic2, firebase-analytics

Till yesterday (June 1st IST) I was able to see user_engagement event in firebase analytics dashboard under events tab but I could not find any user_engagement event from the morning of June 2nd. is it a issue in firebase?

Comment: Reach out to Firebase support

Answer (score 0):

Reached Firebase support. Team has intentionally hidden the user_engagement event from firebase console for only one day. Now we are able to see that event in console. I also requested firebase team not to hide this event in future as it's very important.